# Starting index for geometric series test

Tags: calculus, geometric-series

I was just wondering if the geometric series test for series of the form $\sum_{n=}^{\infty}ar^{n}$ needs the index to start at $0$ or $1$? From my understanding of the proof using partial sums, calculating the convergent value as $\frac{a}{1-r}$ requires the series to start at $0$. I ask because I've been seeing a lot of post and even my assignment solutions neglecting whether it starts at $1$ or $0$. If my assignment assumes I do not know how to change indices when it starts at $n=1$, and this happens to not be negligible, how do I go around using the geometric series test and calculating the convergent value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that for the geometric series

$$\ S_n = \sum_{j=0}^n ar^j = \frac{ar^{n+1}-a}{r-1}\implies \quad |r|<1\quad S_{\infty}=\frac{a}{1-r}
$$

then if we start from $n=1$

$$\ S_n = \sum_{j=1}^n ar^j = \frac{ar^{n+1}-a}{r-1}-a\implies \quad |r|<1\quad S_{\infty}=\frac{a}{1-r}-a$$

Comment: That makes sense since I came up with$\quad\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}ar^n\quad =\quad lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}S_n=\quad \frac{ar}{1-r}\quad$ for $\quad|r|<1$ when n starts at 1, which is: $$S_{\infty}=\frac{a}{1-r}-a$$ with some some algebraic manipulation. Thanks!

Comment: Yes exactly, when we start from $n=i> 0$ we can consider the standard sum for $n=0$ and subtract the terms up to $i-1$.

Answer (score 2):

The starting index is irrelevant to determine whether a geometric series converges (or in general whether a series converges). All that matters to see if a geometric series converges is that the common ratio $r$ be such that $|r|<1$ . Further the value of a geometric series with initial term $a$ and common ratio $r$ is
$$
\frac{a}{1-r}
$$

Comment: The key here is the initial term equal to $a$, and that only happens when $|r|<1$ if n starts at 0. That is $ar^{0}=a$